# The argument of type null should explicitly be cast to Class<?>[] for the invocation of the varargs method

Tags: java, reflection, compiler-warnings, variadic-functions

Please have a look at the following example, the first call to `getMethod()` produces a Warning in Eclipse. The second one doesn't work and fails with a `NoSuchMethodException`.

> The argument of type `null` should explicitly be cast to `Class<?>[]` for the invocation of the varargs method `getMethod(String, Class<?>...)` from type `Class<Example>`. It could alternatively be cast to Class for a varargs invocation.

I followed the warning and nothing worked anymore.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class Example
{
  public void exampleMethod() { }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
  {
   Method defaultNull = Example.class.getMethod("exampleMethod", null);         
   Method castedNull = Example.class.getMethod("exampleMethod", (Class<?>) null);
 }
}
```

The second call produces this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
    Example.exampleMethod(null)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
        at Example.main(Example.java:12)
```

Can someone explain this behaviour to me? What's the correct way to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The second parameter to the `getMethod` method is a VarArg argument.
The correct use is :
If reflected method has no parameter, then no second parameter should be specified.
If the reflected method has parameter, so each parameter should be specified in the next way:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class Example {

    public void exampleMethodNoParam() {
        System.out.println("No params");
    }

    public void exampleMethodWithParam(String arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Example example = new Example();
        Method noParam = Example.class.getMethod("exampleMethodNoParam");
        Method stringParam = Example.class.getMethod("exampleMethodWithParam", String.class);
        noParam.invoke(example);
        stringParam.invoke(example, "test");
        //output 
        //No params
        //test
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So, in your case, when you specify `null` the compiler doesn't know what type do you specify. When you try to cast the `null` to a Class which is unknown but anyway is a class, you get an exception because there is no

`public void exampleMethod(Class<?> object) { }`

signature of exampleMethod.

Comment: How does a casted `null` differs from an uncasted `null`? I can't see this in the JDK source code.

Answer (score 3):

The getMethod defined in java API is:

```
Method java.lang.Class.getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)
```

If the method you called has no arguments,then you should supply a empty array or a array with 0 length for the second argument.like this:

```
Method defaultNull = Example.class.getMethod("exampleMethod", new Class<?>[0]);
```

Invoke the method you should also set a empty array.

```
defaultNull.invoke(example , new Object[0]);
```

Comment: This might work, but is not the intended use. See StKiller's answer for best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't cast `null` to `Class<?>[]`, you cast it to `Class<?>`. Since no method matches that signature, it throws the exception. Correct your cast to properly identify the array.

Comment: Even if the null was cast to Class<?>[] I don't think this would work...  Then the reflection would looked for a method with took an array of Objects?  Which also doesn't exist.